# how to write this query SQL-server 2014

Tags: sql-server

This is my table structure:

```
id value
1 -1
1  0
1 -11
3 -1
3  9
2 -1
2 -3
2 -8
2 -10
```

`output = 2`

how can I select `id` where all values are `negative`

```
select id from table where value <0
```

but it gives other id also !

I need to select id with all values are `negative`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If they're all negative, then the *largest* of them will be negative also:

```
select id
from table
group by id
having MAX(Value) < 0
```

In general, if you want to consider multiple rows together, you'll use some form of `GROUP BY` clause to say how different rows are related. `HAVING` lets you make assertions about the *groups* of rows, which is different from `WHERE` where you make assertions about individual rows, before they form into groups.

Comment: thanks! `If they're all negative then largest of them is also negative` i can't upvote this answer:(